# cc2541 priority of timer1 interrupt vs control loop

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, 8051, texas-instruments

I'm programming and 8051 inside a TI CC2541 BLE chip.  How are priorities handled between timer interrupt call backs and events executed on the event loop?

The reason I'm using the timer1 interrupt to read i2c is because i would like to sample at every 10ms, while the event loop does not guarantee me that time period(in the Sensor tag sample code i2c is read from the event loop).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: It depends on how you set up your system.

Scenario 1)
The 'event loop' is the 'normal' loop which checks what to do (polling) all the time.
Timer interrupt is initialized during startup and never disabled.

-> Timer Interrupt has higher priority than 'event loop'

Scenario 2)
The 'event loop' is the 'normal' loop which checks what to do (polling) all the time.
Timer interrupt is initialized during startup. The event loop disables timer interrupt during certain important operations.

-> Timer Interrupt has higher priority than the normal code in the 'event loop'. It has lower priority than the 'important operations' of the event loop.